# Algorithm for ordering the order of responders at election hustings

Tags: algorithm

For our local election hustings, someone from the audience asks a question and then the candidates take it in turns to answer it. The host decides which order the candidates should answer for each question.

There will probably be 5 candidates at the hustings, though it could be up to 7 or as few as 4.

The host wants to produce the fairest possible order for candidates to answer questions, so that one candidate doesn't answer first or last more frequently than other candidates. Also, he wants candidates to talk before and after each other with a roughly equal distribution.

(I have assigned each candidate a letter between A - E, and then candidates will draw from a hat on the night to choose their letter.)

So, for example:

- ABCDE followed by ADCBE would be bad because A starts and E finishes both times.
- ABCDE followed by ABECD would be bad because B follows A and D follows C both times.
- ABCDE followed by DCEBA would satisfy all requirements.

The number of questions is variable - could be anywhere between 4 and 15.

The host wants a reproducible process that could be audited by the electoral commission if necessary, to establish that the selection process was fair. This rules out my initial approach of "produce a random list, and then edit it manually".  Performance doesn't really matter - it can take up to 10 minutes to run, on a quad-core machine with 16GB RAM.

So far I have tried:

- Just producing a random list. This tends to fail on the constraints - if I keep running it until I get a list that feels right, it fails the 'reproducible' requirement.
- Calling the `levenshtein` algorithm recursively for all combinations, and taking the ones that give the highest overall score. But with so many possible combinations, it's not possible to try all of them. It also doesn't produce great results - it lets a lot of the 'B follows A 3 times in a row' type problems.

I realise that I'm probably over-engineering the solution, but I'm interested in how I would solve this if it needed to be rock solid.

Comment: So input would be number of candidates `N` and number of questions `Q` and the output should be a list of size `Q` where each item is a permutation of the `N` candidates?

Comment: @Simon If you've got 5 candidates (A, B, C, D and E) and three questions, I need a list like `["ABCDE", "BAEDC", "DEBCA"]` that shows what order each candidate should answer for each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question, got me thinking for 10 minutes before I can arrive at some solution.

I have an approach in mind that, I would like to discuss here.

So let's take an example to understand the approach I have in mind.

```
Input: Candidates - [A,B,C,D,E] and 3 questions.

Step1. Let's generate all the possible combinations of the candidates,
       ex:- A,B,C,D,E | A,C,B,D,E ..... D,E,B,C,A etc.

Step2. Take first string A,B,C,D,E and make use of two pointers, one
       starting at beginning and other starting at the end, like this

       A B C D E
       ^       ^
       |       |

Step3. So for first question our order will be like this - A,B,C,D,E
Step4. For the next question increment beginning pointer and decrement ending pointer.

Step5. So for the next question our pointers look like this

       A B C D E
         ^   ^
         |   |

Step6. So out of the calculated permutations select that permutation which
       has B in the starting and D in the ending.
       So for the second question, our configuration would look like this  
       B,A,C,E,D

Step7. Increment the same starting pointer and decrement the ending pointer
       in the same fashion for the next questions also.

Step8. Now when increment pointer reaches the end or decrement pointer
       reaches the start then reverse them and we took A,B,C,D,E as our
       string to move pointers.
       Now take another string to move pointers on.
```

According to me this flow could give a more equal distribution of opportunities for answering the questions.

This algorithm could be a starting point and we can update some parts of it to randomly select pointers or string etc.

Hope this helps!